# Htaccess не дает доступа ко всем страницам, кроме одной

Tags: .htaccess

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
//htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]
```

После добавления данных строк в htaccess, я настроил на сайте чпу. Появилась маленькая проблемка. Кроме файла index.php на хостинге нельзя открыть другую страницу/файл (index_old.php, image.jpg)

Может кто подсказать, как поправить htaccess, что бы доступ к другим файлам тоже был?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё правильно... такой записью вы перенаправляете все запросы на `index.php?my=GET`- строка
Укажите, какого вида ваши ЧПУ, тогда будет понятно как правильно...

Comment: эмм.. это да. Я имел ввиду другое. Если рядом с index.php лежит index.html, и я в адресе ввиду mysite.ru/index_old.php -> открывается index.php, у которого есть get переменная. А охота открыть старый добрый index_old.php

Comment: не совсем понял что нужно... напишите, как должно быть... из чего во что?

Comment: mysite.ru/index_old.php - не могу зайти на эту страницу. как и на mysite.ru/test.php. т.е. теперь работает только одна страница index.php. Охота, что бы работали все, а чпу было только у index.php

Comment: где у вас ЧПУ?
если правильно понял, может так?
RewriteRule ^[^.]+\\.[^.]+\?my=(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]
или так?
RewriteRule ^index\\.[^.]+\?my=(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Супер! Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Один из вариантов - воспользоваться директивой [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond). Их можно указать несколько подряд и все они последовательно будут применены к URI до ближайшей директивы RewriteRule. Если все они выполняются, то RewriteRule сработает.

Вы можете попробовать сделать так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index_old\.php.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В данном случае RewriteRule будет выполнена, если запрос не начинается с /index_old.php и не заканчивается на .jpg

Comment: Ответ классный, жаль не могу всем акцепт влепить

Comment: Решение товарища @thunder более универсально. Если файл не существует, то только тогда будет переадресация

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]
```

это проверит если не файл и не директория, то будет выполнено последнее условие...

Comment: Возьму этот код на вооружение